# Adding a while loop to continue or exit the console in C++

Tags: c++

Hey guys basically I need to put a while loop in my code for example a user can enter the number of tickets for the children and adding -1 to stop. Can you teach me how and where to put my while loop? Its my first time taking a C++ class. I would greatly appreciate your help guys. here is my code and an example of the output.

### Example output

```
          Chesapeake Amusement Park

Enter children ticets or -1 to stop... 10
Enter adult tickets................... 11

          Chesapeake Amusement Park
        ----------------------------

        Tickets      Price       Total
Child         10         10.00        10.00
Adult         11         20.50        220.50

          21

Security Fee                        15.00

 Total Bill                    $  335.00

 Cash received.....340

 Change                                4.50

Enter children tickets or -1 to stop...
```

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double ADULTPRICE = 20.50;
const double SECURITYFEE = 15.00;

int main ()
{
    double adultTotal, childTotal, totalBill, change, cash;
    double CHILDPRICE = 12.00;
    int childTix, adultTix, tixTotal;

    cout << "\n           Chesapeake Amusement Park" << endl << endl;

    cout << "    Enter children tickets or -1 to stop... ";
    cin >> childTix;

    if (childTix >= 8)
        CHILDPRICE = 10.00;

    cout << "    Enter adult tickets.................... ";
    cin >> adultTix;

    childTotal = CHILDPRICE * childTix;
    adultTotal = ADULTPRICE * adultTix;
    totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    cout << "\n\n                 Chesapeake Amusement Park";
    cout << "\n                 -------------------------";
    cout << "\n\n               Tickets      Price      Total\n";

    cout << "     Children   " << setw(3)  << childTix
    << setw(14) << CHILDPRICE
    << setw(11) << childTotal;

    cout << "\n     Adults     " << setw(3)  << adultTix
    << setw(14) << ADULTPRICE
    << setw(11) << adultTotal;

    tixTotal = childTix + adultTix;

    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n        "          << setw(11) << tixTotal;
    cout << "\n ";

    if ((tixTotal >= 20) || (childTix >= 14))
        cout << "\n       Security Fee           " << setw(14) << SECURITYFEE;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n         Total Bill             $" << setw(11) << totalBill;

    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n         Cash received...... ";
    cin >> cash;

    change = cash - totalBill;

    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n     Change                  " << setw(11) << change;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: No offense but by asking for help in this you're missing out on the most important thing to learn (more important than knowledge of the syntax itself imo): Problem solving. Programming is not knowledge of a programming language, it's a way of thinking.

Comment: Anyway, just imagine what parts of the code you want to be repeated and encapsulate that in the while loop.. and add some check to if -1 was entered and if so, just break out of the loop with the break syntax.

Comment: @JonasB: you are right , but please see ' Its my first time taking a C++ class' . when i was in my 1st class i could not even write the code which he wrote . I learnt many things from other's codes , which i could not have thought myself :)

Comment: @JonasB I should have included that I know that the while statement is probably going to be  "while (childTix != 1)" but I just dont know where to put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is great as a beginner! You just need to do minor changes to your code.

The primary change is to use a correct while expression to make the loop stops when the user inputs (-1) as a value for ***childTix***. I do not recommend that you use the ***break*** keyword to exist the loop. You should always try to stop the loop naturally by letting the while expression be evaluated to ***FALSE***. This makes your program easier to read and trace.

Another thing you need to add is the constant variable ***DISCOUNTEDCHILDPRICE*** when the number of children tickets is greater than 7. You cannot play with the value of ***CHILDPRICE*** inside the while loop cause this will lead to inconsistent results after you run the while loop the next time if the number of child tickets is less than 8. Instead, use if statement inside the body of the loop to figure out if there is a discount or not on children' tickets.

There is also a few other changes not mentioned above.

Here is the revised version of your code. I put the whole program so you and other beginners can learn from it and avoid having such problems in your future programs.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

const double ADULTPRICE = 20.50;
const double SECURITYFEE = 15.00;
const double CHILDPRICE = 12.00;
const double DISCOUNTEDCHILDPRICE = 10;

int main()
{
    double adultTotal, childTotal, totalBill, change, cash;
    int childTix, adultTix, tixTotal;

    cout << "\n           Chesapeake Amusement Park" << endl << endl;
    cout << "    Enter children tickets or -1 to stop... ";
    cin >> childTix;

    while (childTix != -1)
    {
        cout << "    Enter adult tickets.................... ";
        cin >> adultTix;

        if (childTix < 8)
            childTotal = CHILDPRICE * childTix;
        else
            childTotal = DISCOUNTEDCHILDPRICE * childTix;

        adultTotal = ADULTPRICE * adultTix;
        totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;

        cout.setf(ios::fixed);
        cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
        cout.precision(2);

        cout << "\n\n                 Chesapeake Amusement Park";
        cout << "\n                 -------------------------";
        cout << "\n\n               Tickets      Price      Total\n";

        cout << "     Children   " << setw(3) << childTix
            << setw(14) << CHILDPRICE
            << setw(11) << childTotal;

        cout << "\n     Adults     " << setw(3) << adultTix
            << setw(14) << ADULTPRICE
            << setw(11) << adultTotal;

        tixTotal = childTix + adultTix;

        cout << "\n\n        " << setw(11) << tixTotal;
        cout << "\n ";

        if ((tixTotal >= 20) || (childTix >= 14))
            cout << "\n       Security Fee           " << setw(14) << SECURITYFEE;

        cout << "\n\n         Total Bill             $" << setw(11) << totalBill;

        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "\n         Cash received...... ";
        cin >> cash;

        change = cash - totalBill;

        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "\n     Change                  " << setw(11) << change;

        cout << "\n           Chesapeake Amusement Park" << endl << endl;
        cout << "    Enter children tickets or -1 to stop... ";
        cin >> childTix;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! This is excellent coding sir, now my code looks more presentable and neat. The DISCOUNTEDCHILDPRICE is exactly what I should have added and not just depend on an "if" statement because I noticed that it is acting funny sometimes. The while loop though I know that the while loop is "while (childTix != -1)" but I somehow forgot to include it in my code. I just do now know where to start and end it. Thank you very much sir! You helped me alot and learned from this.

Answer (score 0):

First try on your own , then see the solution .

```
while(1)
{

    cout << "    Enter adult tickets.................... ";
    cin >> adultTix;

    if(adultTix == -1)
        break;


    childTotal = CHILDPRICE * childTix;
    adultTotal = ADULTPRICE * adultTix;
    totalBill = childTotal + adultTotal;

    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    cout << "\n\n                 Chesapeake Amusement Park";
    cout << "\n                 -------------------------";
    cout << "\n\n               Tickets      Price      Total\n";

    cout << "     Children   " << setw(3)  << childTix  
                               << setw(14) << CHILDPRICE 
                               << setw(11) << childTotal;

    cout << "\n     Adults     " << setw(3)  << adultTix  
                                 << setw(14) << ADULTPRICE 
                                 << setw(11) << adultTotal;

    tixTotal = childTix + adultTix;

    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n        "          << setw(11) << tixTotal;
    cout << "\n ";

    if ((tixTotal >= 20) || (childTix >= 14))
        cout << "\n       Security Fee           " << setw(14) << SECURITYFEE;

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n         Total Bill             $" << setw(11) << totalBill;

    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n         Cash received...... ";
    cin >> cash;

    change = cash - totalBill;

    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n ";
    cout << "\n     Change                  " << setw(11) << change;

}
```

Another way of writing while loop is `for( ; ; )` . The main point was to use keyword `break`  .